# Macro to find specific string and select row in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How do I find a cell containing a certain string in a certain column, then select a specific range of cells (say the 5 subsequent cells) in the same row using VBA?

To formulate the question better, I might have cells containing strings which contain the string "apples" in column `A`. I want to search column `A` for that "apples" and find **any** cells in that column which contain the string. The, if that turns out to be in cells `A1` and `A8`, I want to select cells `B2:F2` and `B8:F8`.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: [How to use .Find](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A data filter in the spreadsheet might do most of this for you, ie just look for apple and it will only show those rows, after which you can select them. VBA can apply a data filter.